# Android 11 - import non media file from Download

Tags: android, file, download, storage-access-framework

Our android business application can export data and send them through email to customer. Customer opens email and downloads attachment to "Download" folder. Now business application on customer side must take downloaded data file and import it. Google play blocks direct file access for standard applications, we must use SAF. However, SAF cannot access non media files from Download folder. Do I must to tell to all customers that they must manually copy/paste downloaded file using external file manager to the folder which our business application can read? Or is there some way how to access non media files from Download folder using SAF or similar way?

Comment: `SAF cannot access non media files from Download folder. ` SAF can access any file. Also from Download folder.

Comment: Hm, how? Because I cant grant SAF permission  on root of Download folder.

Comment: Well show your code suitable for media files. After that i will tell you that any file can be picked with it. And you cannot grant access. You will be given access

Comment: Updated. I attached function, it returns list of files from given uri (folder)

Comment: On Android 11+ the user cannot pick the Download folder. So you cannot list any file. Not even media files. Where are you talking about,?

Comment: Please read my post and questions carefully.